# Почему нельзя вызвать метод String.Substring

Tags: c#, строки

Почему я могу вызвать метод класса String только от переменной типа string:

```
string text = "Hello World"
text.Substring(...)
```

А не напрямую от класса String:

```
String.Substring(...)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Потому что это метод экземпляра класса, а не статический. Зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: А, все, увидел. Просто было интересно.

Comment: нужно присвоить результат вызова `text.Substring(...)`, иначе результат потеряется, и это будет напрасный вызов.